# Prevent mmenu to automatically open when page loaded

Tags: mmenu

Every time my web page is loaded, the mmenu always open automatically, how to prevent mmenu to automatically open when page loaded?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the menu ID appears in the browser address bar as a URL hash.

For example, if the href of the link that opens your menu is `#my-menu`, loading this in the address bar will automatically open the menu when the page loads:

```
https://example.com#my-menu
```

Conversely, omitting the hash will load the page with the menu closed:

```
https://example.com
```

[mmenu documentation](https://mmenujs.com/docs/)